# Proving that a set of functions is a linear subspace of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

I am attempting to solve the following problem:

Let $V$ be the vector space of all continuous functions $f : R → R$ with point-wise addition and scalar multiplication defined.

(a) Show that
$M_1$ = {$f ∈ V :$ There exists $a, b ∈ R$ with $f(x) = a sin(x + b)$ for all $x ∈ R$}
is a linear subspace of $V$.

(b) Show that
$M_2$ = {$f ∈ V :$ There exists $a ∈ R$ with $f(x) = sin(ax)$ for all $x ∈ R$}
is not a linear subspace of $V$.

As far as I understand, the requirement for being a linear subspace is that the set must be algebraically closed with respect to addition and multiplication by a scalar, that is,

(i) If $f_1,f_2 ∈ V$ then $f_1+f_2 ∈ V$

(ii) If $f ∈ V$ then $λf ∈ V$, where $λ∈R$

However, trying to apply the first condition to prove part (a), I need to find a way to express

$(f_1+f_2)(x)=f_1(x)+f_2(x)=a_1sin(x+b_1)+a_2sin(x+b_2)$

in the form

$asin(x+b)$

so that I can prove that the sum of the two functions belongs to $M_1$ as well.
Further, the second condition (multiplication by a scalar) is valid as $(λf)(x)=λasin(x+b)$ which belongs to $M_1$. It is just the first condition at which I am stuck.

Also, for part (b), I would appreciate hints for proving how the set is *not* a linear subspace? What would be a way of showing conclusively that the two conditions do not hold?

Comment: For part (b), note that your set is not closed under scalar multiplication. Indeed, $f(x) = \sin(x) \in M_{2}$, but $g(x) = 3\sin(x)$ is not, as $\sin(ax)$ is bounded between $-1$ and $1$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You miss one condition. (iii) the subspace-to-be is not empty

Comment: @AlexWertheim Ah, I see now. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have
\begin{align}
a_1\sin(x+b_1)+a_2\sin(x+b_2)&=a_1\sin x\cos b_1+a_1\cos x\sin b_1+a_2\sin x\cos b_2+a_2\cos x\sin b_2\\
&=(a_1\cos b_1+a_2\cos b_2)\sin x+(a_1\sin b_1+a_2\sin b_2)\cos x.
\end{align}
So it is enough to show that $\alpha\sin x+\beta\cos x\in M_1$. For this, note that we can always find $t$ with 
$$
\frac\alpha{\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}}=\cos t,\ \ \ 
\frac\beta{\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}}=\sin t.
$$
So
\begin{align}
\alpha\sin x+\beta\cos x&=\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}\,(\cos t\sin x+\sin t\cos x)\\
&=\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}\,\sin(x+t)\in M_1.
\end{align}
For $M_2$, as Alex noted, all elements $\sin (ax)$ have absolute value $\leq1$, so $5\sin x$ cannot be written as $\sin (ax)$.

Comment: Thanks for responding! Interesting point about the cosines being included in $M_1$, but I do not quite understand how the sum obtained in the final step belongs to $M_1$. I don't see how it can be expressed in the form $asin(x+b)$ which is the general form for any element of $M_1$.

Comment: You are totally right, I was always thinking that $M_1$ was the span of said functions. I'm busy right now, but I'll think about it soon.

Comment: I'm back. Please see the edit.

Comment: Brilliant! I'd never have thought of expressing $α$ and $β$ in terms of $t$ in such a way, and it unlocks the problem so smoothly! Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help.